# help with finding that $f(x) =g(x)$

Tags: derivatives, limits-without-lhopital

I am trying to multiply $f(x)$ with the given equation to get $g(x)$ but I am not getting the right answer. Any help would be appreciated. The link to the question is posted.

> Define functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ by
>   $$
> f(x) = \frac{\sqrt[3]{x} - 2}{x-8}, \quad g(x) = \frac1{\sqrt[3]{x^2} + 2\sqrt[3]x + 4}
> $$
>   By multiplying $f(x)$ by $\frac{\sqrt[3]{x^2} + 2\sqrt[3]x + 4}{\sqrt[3]{x^2} + 2\sqrt[3]x + 4}$, show that $f(x) = g(x)$ for all real numbers $x\neq 2$.

Comment: The problem statement tells you exactly what you need to do. Did you try that? How far did you get? Show us where you are stuck, and we can help you get through the parts you didn't understand. As a side note, I would recommend you multiply $g(x)$ by $\frac{\sqrt[3]{x} - 2}{\sqrt[3]{x} - 2}$ rahter than what the problem suggests. On the other hand, the problem doesn't phrase it as a hint, so it might not be optional.

Comment: Show us what you've tried, so we can point out your mistake.

Comment: wouldnt i just be able to cancel the equation because the numerator and the denominator is the same? so im just left with fx

Comment: @ssgg1 That's the point. Value-wise, you're just multiplying by $1$, so you do technically get left with just $f(x)$. However, the _expressions_ in the numerator and the denominator of $f$ change if you carry out the multiplication (especially in the numerator) _before_ you simplify. This will ultimately make it easier to compare with $g$.

Comment: this is what I have so far: ((cube root x)-2 / x-8) x ((cube root x)+2)^2 / ((cube root x)+2)^2. any idea how to proceed?

Comment: @ssgg1 Carry out the multiplication, as I said.

Comment: hmm still not getting the write answer

Answer (score 0):

The only computation you really need is to see that 
$$(x^{1/3}-2)*(x^{2/3}+2x^{1/3}+4)=x-8.$$

The rest is simple algebra, for let there be three functions $f_1, f_2, f_3$ such that $f_1*f_3=f_2$, then

$$\frac{f_1}{f_2}*\frac{f_3}{f_3}= \frac{f_2}{f_2*f_3}=\frac{1}{f_3},$$

which proves out result if $f_1=x^{1/3}-2$, $f_2=x-8$ and $f_3=x^{2/3}+2x^{1/3}+4$.